# Black Ops 2 freezes on start up

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I'm trying to play Call of Duty: Black Ops 2 and I keeps freezing when the Dolby logo comes up. I have currently have a perfect internet connection and my disc is not dirty or scratched; it works perfectly for my brother. I also tried to clear the cache but it still doesn't work. It's been going on for a year.

Comment: What do you mean "works perfectly for my brother"? The same disc, the same console?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is when you say that it works fine for your brother. I also am starting to think that it is a hardware Console Disc read problem. Try inserting other disks to confirm or deny. If that is the case you will need to replace the laser inside.

Here are some links to some semi-helpful articles:

- [Sony Community Forum Post](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-Support/MW3-Freezing-and-quot-Disk-Read-Error-quot/td-p/37314802)
- [Sony Community Fix User-Made Fix Guide](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-Support/Your-PS3-stopped-reading-discs-Is-the-laser-broken-or-is-the/td-p/17475399)
- [HubPages Fix Page](http://peteong.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-fix-the-PS3-Disk-read-error)

Hope this works out. Good luck.

Comment: If other discs read and play fine on your system then it is some unfortunate deformation or very small scratch or crack on the disc. I am also assuming that by "works for my brother" you mean "plays fine in his xbox" which is curious and odd. as your laser leads to freeze his does not. could still just be that yours is on its way out. are both xboxs around the same age? and get similar amounts of use? One thing to try, worked when i started to have read errors and other issues. see if you can install the game to your HDD, you still need the disc to read. but not as much or as often, when insta

Comment: lled. i can understand having a character limit but ...come on.